# Batch File Randomising from 0 to Variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, random

For a long time I have wanted to program a game and I always thought it would be too difficult, so I started programming in the popular site Scratch (https://www.scratch.mit.edu) and doing websites with html and css.

I started to want to actually make a game with code so I am learning batch files. Unfortunately I only just started and am confused with a section on the game. I am making a game to try and recreate the game Swords and Sandals 2 to improve my knowledge of batch files. The important part of the game is the damage you deal to your opposition. Obviously you need a percentage chance for your attack to work to input luck into the game. I could easily do that but I want it so that if you have a higher level variable you will have a higher percentage chance, but if your opponent has some defence it will reduce the chance.

I did some basic maths to come up with some equations I was happy with, so here is the section of code :

```
if %move% equ 2 set /a tauntchance=%RANDOM%*(100+(%oppdefence%*5))/32768+1
if %move% equ 2 set /a tauntchance1=(7+(%charisma%*3))
if %move% equ 2 if tauntchance leq %tauntchance1% set /a damage= ((%charisma%*2)-%RANDOM%*1/32768+1)
if %move% equ 2 set /a energy=%energy%-%charisma%
```

move=The chosen option

tauntchance=A random number from 0-(100+(The opponents defence*5))

tauntchance1=(7+(Your charisma level*3))

3rd Line= If tauntchance is less than or equal to tauntchance1 then set your damage to Your Charisma Level*2 with a 50% chance to remove 1 or 0, which just stays the same.

4th Line= External variables including your energy amount.

When I run this code the window crashes. If you know if this is possible please let me know!

I have done lots of previous research without any results on this specific topic.

**EDIT**

With your answers it still just closes the window so I thought I would update the code from the problem onwards.

```
if %move% equ 2 set /a tauntchance=%RANDOM%*(100+(%oppdefence%*5)+1)/32768+1
if %move% equ 2 set /a tauntchance1=(7+(%charisma%*3))
if %move% equ 2 if %tauntchance% leq %tauntchance1% set /a damage=((%charisma%*2)-%RANDOM%*2/32768+1)
if %move% equ 2 set /a energy=%energy%-%charisma%
echo You have %energy%/%maxenergy% energy left.
echo.
echo You dealt %damage% damage.
echo.
pause >nul
```

Thank you for the responses anyway!

**RESOLVED**

I found the problem in some variables before in the code and have fixed it, thank you for the help.

Comment: You do not need all te `%%` in a `set /A` commad, so just mentioning the variable names without the `%%` expands their values too; there is an error in your third line, it should read `if %tauntchance% leq %tauntchance1% [...]` (you forgot the `%%` around `tauntchance`); what do you exactly mean with "the window crashes"??

Comment: After I said that the window crashes i made some minor improvements and now it said missing operand, after I added in the %% after and before tauntchance on the third line, it just closes the window even though I put in a pause>nul to stop it.

Comment: 1. there is a space after the `=` in the 3rd line `set /a damage=` -- try to remove it; 2. is your code fragment part of a parenthesised code block?

Comment: If you want to learn about batch files then that's fair enough, although modern Windows scripting is more likely to use PowerShell. However, if you really want to program a game then you'd be better off with a full programming language instead, such as Python or one of the versions of BASIC designed with games in mind. Trying to use batch files for anything non-trivial will become frustrating very quickly.

Comment: Still this problem is still here so I will post the code from the problem to the end in my question.

Answer (score 0):

`set /a tauntchance=%RANDOM%*(100+(%oppdefence%*5))/32768+1`

The value of `%tauntchance%` variable will never be equal to 0. To obtain the desirable result you should use this line

`set /a tauntchance=%RANDOM%*(100+(%oppdefence%*5)+1)/32768`

There is a problem with the 3rd line also. This part of the code
`%random%*1/32768+1` 
will generate a sequence of 1's only, so the value of `%damage%` variable will always stay the same. To fix that use `%random%*2/32768` instead.

Is that a complete code? Because you either have to initialise your variables first or better yet put them in quotation marks when you use them with `if` command. The code below runs fine, except that it is meaningless without the proper values of the variables.

```
@echo off
if "%move%" equ "2" set /a tauntchance=%RANDOM%*(100 + (%oppdefence%*5) + 1)/32768
if "%move%" equ "2" set /a tauntchance1=(7 + (%charisma%*3))
if "%move%" equ "2" if "%tauntchance%" leq "%tauntchance1%" set /a damage=((%charisma%*2) - %RANDOM% %% 2)
if "%move%" equ "2" set /a energy=%energy% - %charisma%
echo You have %energy%/%maxenergy% energy left.
echo.
echo You dealt %damage% damage.
echo.
pause > nul
```

Comment: to get "0" or "1" only, the modulo operator works good: `set /a tauntchance=%RANDOM% %% 2` (on command line: `set /a tauntchance=%RANDOM% % 2`) (spaces can be omitted, but it's better readable with them)